# How Navigate XML with augeas xml

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, puppet, augeas

I have a very strange xml file that i need to update using augeas.

```
<root>
    <node name="Client">
        <node name="Attributes">
            <info>
                <test>
                    <entry><key>colour</key><value type="string">blue</value></entry>
                </test>
            </info>
        </node>
    </node>
    <node name="Network">
        <node name="Server">
            <info>
                <test>
                    <entry><key>transport</key><value type="string">internet</value></entry>
                    <entry><key>ipAddr</key><value type="string">125.125.125.142</value></entry>
                    <entry><key>portNo</key><value type="string">1234</value></entry>
                    <entry><key>protocolType</key><value type="string">tcp</value></entry>
                </test>
            </info>
        </node>
    </node>
</root>
```

I need to update the element "value" which is just after the element "key" which contains the text ipAddr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description of the node you want to update, here's a suggestion:

```
set /files/path/to/your/file.xml//entry[key/#text="ipAddr"]/value/#text "255.255.255.0"
```

This selects the `entry` node at any level in the file, which has a `key/#text` subnode with value `ipAddr` and then it updates its `value/#text` subnode to have value `255.255.255.0`.

Comment: This is giving me <entry><key>ipAddr<value>255.255.255.0</value></key><value type="string">125.125.125.142</value></entry> instead of  <entry><key>ipAddr</key><value type="string">255.255.255.0</value></entry>

Comment: @Vash, I can't reproduce that. The answer seems to work as described for me against the sample file - check you've copied it correctly?

Comment: It works i had the square bracket in the wrong place. Cheers!